# Cloning a local repository to host machine

Tags: git

How to clone a git repository from a Linux VM? All Offline. I can connect to Linux using SSH, but I don't know how to properly pass the repository path. I bridged the connection using my ethernet.

I tried `git clone username@guestIPadd:port/path`, but it didn't work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to clone from?  Is it HTTPS or ssh?

Comment: I'm cloning from a Linux Virtual Machine (VirtualBox) on my Windows Host. I use SSH for connection.

Comment: @Jawad You cannot provide port with scp-like syntax. See the correct syntax at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#_git_urls . Port is only allowed with `ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo`

Comment: Thank you for the helpful guidance. It works now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`git clone username@guestIPadd:/path/to/repository.git`
Try replacing the '/' after Ipadd to a ':'. This might work

Comment: can you tell me what the error message is?